# how do we find the nature of lines represented by a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations, 3d, coordinate-systems

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Esa.jpg)

for example in this question (multi options correct) , solving by Cramer's rule we can conclude the value of Δ ≠ 0 , in order to get a consistent solution as (1,1,1). And similarly the last option would be also be correct , as we can check by solving.

But how we check the nature of lines represented by a system of linear equations? what is the concept here ?

Comment: Can a single Cartesian equation represent a line in 3-D?

Comment: i guess yes , for a simple line equation like ax + by+ cz =0, it represents a line in space .

Comment: No, it does not.